# Time Complexity of recursive of function

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

Need help proving the time complexity of a recursive function.
Supposedly it's 2^n. I need to prove that this is the case.

```
def F(n):
    if  n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        result = 0
        for i in range(n):
            result += F(i)
        return n*result+n`
```

Here's another version that does the same thing. The assignment said to use an array to store values in an attempt to reduce the time complexity so what I did was this

```
def F2(n,array):

    if n < len(array):
        answer = array[n]

    elif  n == 0:
        answer = 0
        array.append(answer)
    else:
        result = 0
        for i in range(n):
              result += F2(i,array)
        answer = n*result+n
        array.append(answer)

    return answer
```

Again what I am looking for is the explanation of how to find the complexities of the two snippets of code, not interested in just knowing the answer.
All and any help greatly appreciated.

PS: for some reason, I can't get "def F2" to stay in the code block...sorry about that

Comment: It's helpful if you give a brief explanation of what your functions are *suppose to do*. Especially when they have names like `F` and `F2`...

Comment: You can prove the `2^n` thing by [induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction).

Comment: This is actually a relatively involved mathematics question, and if you don't get an answer it may be because it is outside of the more technical scope of this site (e.g. how to implement algorithms, why implementations don't work, how to do x in language y, etc.). If you don't get an answer that is why. I recommend look through the methods your course has given you for the determining the big-O of recursive methods. You know for example that `T(n)=T(n-1)+T(n-2)+...+T(1)+T(0)+O(1)` Start from there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, the first function you wrote is an example of `Exhaustive Search` where you are exploring every possible branch that can be formed from a set of whole numbers up to `n` (which you have passed in the argument and you are using `for` loop for that). To explain you the time complexity I am going to consider the recursion stack as a Tree (to represent a recursive function call stack you can either use a stack or use an n-ary Tree)

Let's call you first function `F1`:

F1(3), now three branches will be formed for each number in the set S (set is the whole numbers up to n). I have taken n = 3, coz it will be easy for me to make the diagram for it. You can try will other larger numbers and observe the recursion call stack.

```
    3
   /| \
  0 1  2    ----> the leftmost node is returns 0 coz (n==0) it's the base case 
    |  /\
    0  0 1
         |
         0   ----> returns 0
```

So here you have explored every possibility branches. If you try to write the recursive equation for the above problem then:

```
T(n) = 1; n is 0
     = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + T(n-3) + ... + T(1); otherwise
```

Here,

```
T(n-1) = T(n-2) + T(n-3) + ... T(1).
```

So, `T(n-1) + T(n-2) + T(n-3) + ... + T(1) = T(n-1) + T(n-1)`

So, the Recursive equation becomes:

```
T(n) = 1; n is 0
     = 2*T(n-1); otherwise
```

Now you can easily solve this recurrence relation (or use can use Masters theorem for the fast solution). You will get the **time complexity as `O(2^n)`**.

Solving the recurrence relation:

```
T(n) = 2T(n-1)
     = 2(2T(n-1-1) = 4T(n-2)
     = 4(2T(n-3)
     = 8T(n-3)
     = 2^k T(n-k), for some integer `k` ----> equation 1
```

Now we are given the base case where `n` is `0`, so let,

```
n-k = 0 , i.e. k = n;
```

Put `k = n` in `equation 1`,

```
T(n) = 2^n * T(n-n)
     = 2^n * T(0)
     = 2^n * 1; // as T(0) is 1
     = 2^n
```

So, **T.C = O(2^n)**

So this is how you can get the time complexity for your first function. Next, if you observe the recursion Tree formed above (each node in the tree is a subproblem of the main problem), you will see that the nodes are repeating (i.e. the subproblems are repeating). So you have used a memory in your second function `F2` to store the already computed value and whenever the sub-problems are occurring again (i.e. repeating subproblems) you are using the pre-computed value (this saves time for computing the sub-problems again and again). The approach is also known as Dynamic Programming.

Let's now see the second function, here you are returning `answer`. But, if you see your function you are building an array named as `array` in your program. The main time complexity goes there. Calculating its time complexity is simple because there is always just one level of recursion involved (or casually you can say no recursion involved) as every number `i` which is in range of number `n` is always going to be less than the number `n`, So the first `if` condition gets executed and control returns from there in `F2`. So each call can't go deeper than 2 level in the call stack.

So,

```
Time complexity of second function = time taken to build the array;
                                   = 1 comparisions + 1 comparisions + 2 comparisions + ... + (n-1) comparisions
                                   = 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n-1
                                   = O(n^2).
```

Let me give you a simple way to observe such recursions more deeply. You can print the recursion stack on the console and observe how the function calls are being made. Below I have written your code where I am printing the function calls.

Code:

```
def indent(n):
    for i in xrange(n):
        print '    '*i,

# second argument rec_cnt is just taken to print the indented function properly
def F(n, rec_cnt):
    indent(rec_cnt)
    print 'F(' + str(n) + ')'
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        result = 0
        for i in range(n):
            result += F(i, rec_cnt+1)
        return n*result+n

# third argument is just taken to print the indented function properly
def F2(n, array, rec_cnt):
    indent(rec_cnt)
    print 'F2(' + str(n) + ')'

    if n < len(array):
        answer = array[n]

    elif n == 0:
        answer = 0
        array.append(answer)
    else:
        result = 0
        for i in range(n):
                result += F2(i, array, rec_cnt+1)
        answer = n*result+n
        array.append(answer)

    return answer


print F(4, 1)
lis = []
print F2(4, lis, 1)
```

Now observe the output:

```
 F(4)
      F(0)
      F(1)
               F(0)
      F(2)
               F(0)
               F(1)
                            F(0)
      F(3)
               F(0)
               F(1)
                            F(0)
               F(2)
                            F(0)
                            F(1)
                                             F(0)
96
 F2(4)
      F2(0)
      F2(1)
               F2(0)
      F2(2)
               F2(0)
               F2(1)
      F2(3)
               F2(0)
               F2(1)
               F2(2)
96
```

In the first function call stack i.e. `F1`, you see that each call is explored up to `0`, i.e. we are exploring each possible branch up to `0` (the base case), so, we call it Exhaustive Search.

In the second function call stack, you can see that the function calls are getting only two levels deep, i.e. they are using the pre-computed value to solve the repeated subproblems. Thus, it's time complexity is lesser than `F1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to explain

Comment: did you write T(n-1) + T(n-2) + T(n-3) + ... + T(1) instead of " n(T(n-1) + T(n-2) + T(n-3) + ... + T(1))+n" ( not taking into account the multiplication by n and addition of n) because they are constants and can be ignored when talking of asymptotic complexity?

Comment: Also when applying the Master theorem I don't see any case that would yield an O(2^n) could you show me the steps you used to determine that 

T(n) = 1; n is 0
     = 2*T(n-1);
is of complexity O(2^n)

Comment: `n*result+n` is a constant time operation, the main time in the algorithm is due to the recursion tree being formed. You are wrong when you say, `T(n) = n( T(n-1)+T(n-2)+....+T(0))+n` because T(n) represents the time complexity of the function when `n` is passed as the input to the algorithm. The expression you wrote doesn't make sense, why do you want to multiply the time with `n`?

Comment: Yeah I am sorry. It doesn't make sense now that you put it this way. I just started algorithm analysis and I still find it confusing especially when using recursion, my bad

Comment: I am glad you are learning and happy to help you, I am gonna solve the recurrence relation using the mathematical approach in a while.

Comment: @KarimKamel added the recurrence relation solution part.